# gcovr: How to use Cygwin gcovr package?

Tags: python, unit-testing, gcc, code-coverage, gcovr

I'm using gcov already to get code coverage results. I want to use gcovr. I've installed the gcovr package from Cygwin.

Now, I've never used Python.
I'm confused because I've got `C:\cygwin\lib\python2.7\site-packages\gcovr` 
with `init.py`, `init.pyc` and `init.pyo` files

Under `C:\cygwin\bin` I've got a `gcovr` file and also `python.exe`

I ran `python.exe` from command prompt and it says `Python 2.7.13 (default, Mar 14 2017, 23:27:55) [GCC 5.4.0] on cygwin` (is this what I have to use for gcovr?)

I tried `>>>python2.7 gcovr` with the full gcovr path mentioned above and I get

**SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

I tried `>>>gcovr` and I get

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

**File (stdin); line 1, in (module)**

**NameError: name 'gcovr' is not defined**

I went through the help utility and looked at all the modules, gcovr *was* one of them.

I've seen usage like `../../../scripts/gcovr -r` but I don't have a scripts folder.

What am I missing? What steps should I follow?

Comment: Can you just try running gcovr from the cygwin bash shell? Also, how did you install the gcovr package?

Answer (score 0):

Try `gcovr -r ./` and `gcovr -r ./ --branches` from the root folder where you have your .gcno and .gcda files to get the summary of line and branch coverage respectively